# Can I perform topological sorting on cycle graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am told to perform a attempted topological sorting on cycle graph (non acyclic). Can I do so? Since a topological sorting only can be perform on a dag(directed acyclic graph).

[Click here to view the question with the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIJu1.png)

Comment: No. A topological sorting is possible if and only if the graph is a DAG.

Comment: Yes I know, only dag can be performed using topological sorting but the question told us to perform a topological sorting on the non dag. How do I do so? I have edited my question with the image

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you to topologically sort a cyclic graph. It asks you to try (hand simulating) running the algorithm on a particular cyclic graph. Doing so will show you something about the algorithm, which is why the authors ask you to do it.

Comment: it says run the algorithm for computing a(n) (attempted) "topological sorting" on the following digraph. there is a word topological sorting there. Okay so by doing so do I just show the directed graph with its finishing and discovery time?

Comment: Yes. And "attempt to apply merge-sort to the list [1, 5, 3, egg, book]" has the word "sort" in it, but it doesn't say that you're sorting the list. In making the attempt, you'll realize that "egg" and 5 are not comparable, which is why having the input of merge-sort consist of items that are comparable is important.  I've taught courses containing exercises exactly like this. The idea really is exactly the one I've stated. But if you'd rather feel that the authors have written something mistaken, and you're oh-so-clever for having caught the error, go right ahead. The authors won't mind.

Comment: Okay I will only need to show the digraph with its finishing and discovering time am I right?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a *cyclic-toposort* project that aims to sort directed cyclic graphs by determining the least amount of cyclic edges that would result in a sortable directed acyclic graph. I published the **[cyclic_toposort](https://github.com/PaulPauls/cyclic-toposort)** project on github. It not only quickly sorts a directed cyclic graph providing the minimal amount of violating edges but also optionally provides the maximum groupings of nodes that are on the same topological level (and can therefore be activated at the same time) if desired.

If the problem is still relevant to you then I would be happy if you check out my project and let me know what you think!

This project was useful to my own neural network topology research, so I had to create something like this anyway. I am answering your question this late in case anyone else stumbles upon this thread in search for the same question.